# Find an example of unbounded subset of complex set.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find an example of unbounded subset of complex set.

**Attempt:**
The set $A=\{e^{z}: z \in \Bbb C\} \subseteq \Bbb C$ is unbounded over $\Bbb C$.

**Proof**
Let $M>0$ be an arbitrary real number.
Then there exists $z=e^{\ln (M+1)} \in A$ such that
\begin{align*}
|z| &= |e^{\ln(M+1)}| \\
&= e^{\ln(M+1)} \\
&= M+1 \ge M.
\end{align*}
Hence, $A$ is unbounded.

But, I'm not sure that this is correct.

Comment: Its look fine, the only comment is on the notation, it is convenient to use $z$ instead of $z_0$, since $z_0$ is usually understood as a constant.

Anothe easier example is a line, for example the real line view as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ or the imaginary line.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Okay, sir. Thanks

Comment: what about Reals numbers